# unable to start logstash in windows,"Active" keyword appear

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

base on windows
unzip the file of `logstash-7.10.0-windows-x86_64.zip` ,then run `cmd` like this:

[image]

it does not work;

Comment: cmd print ```Using JAVA_HOME defined java: G:\Java_Development_Tools\JDK8_64
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
: Ҳ޷ Active```

Comment: The problem is solved ,.The reason is that I modified the `cmd` encoding of the registry, which caused `jvm.options` to be read during initialization.Then it appended the `Active code page: 65001` ,so it reported the `Active` keyword error. I edited the file `logstash.bat`------>`echo %LS_JAVA_OPTS%
set JAVA_OPTS=%LS_JAVA_OPTS:~25%`,then it is ok.